# Travel Distance between two Lat and Long

Tags: android, google-api, latitude-longitude, google-directions-api

I am looking to calculate and give the distance between two sets of Lat and Long for travel on Road.

I have had a look at the Google's Directions and Distance Matrix API. And also done a lot of other questions on SO.

But i am not able to figure out the best possible way to do it, you need to calculate the distance to around 20-25 locations at each time.

We are building a travel app that requires this information for the user on Android device from where he is.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If You are looking for driving distance NOT shortest distance then You can try to call API service with URL like:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=54.406505,18.67708&destinations=54.446251,18.570993&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false
```

This will result in JSON like this:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Powstańców Warszawy 8, Sopot, Polska" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "majora Henryka Sucharskiego 69, Gdańsk, Polska" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "24,7 km",
                  "value" : 24653
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "34 min",
                  "value" : 2062
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Result distance is actual road distance between two locations.

You can find more details in [The Google Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/)

Comment: does this have an api limit ?

Comment: Yes, it does have an api limit. It's all described in document I provided in the answer.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to search a little more before you ask.

Anyways, use the Haversine formula

```
rad = function(x) {return x*Math.PI/180;}

distHaversine = function(p1, p2) {
  var R = 6371; // earth's mean radius in km
  var dLat  = rad(p2.lat() - p1.lat());
  var dLong = rad(p2.lng() - p1.lng());

  var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
          Math.cos(rad(p1.lat())) * Math.cos(rad(p2.lat())) * Math.sin(dLong/2) * Math.sin(dLong/2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
  var dist = R * c;

  return dist.toFixed(3);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**It give the distance between two locations.**

First you need to get latitude, longitude of source and same for destination. Pass these in this method.

It return you distance between them.

```
public float distanceFrom(float lat1, float lng1, float lat2, float lng2) {
    double earthRadius = 3958.75;
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    double dist = earthRadius * c;
    int meterConversion = 1609;
    return new Float(dist * meterConversion).floatValue();
}
```