# Loading KML file when area visible in google map android

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

I am working on google maps application and I have data in KML file of 1 area. I can successfully add the layer to map when a button is pressed, Now I am searching a way to add the layer when a user viewing that area at a particular zoom level. I can able to add a layer at a particular zoom level that I want but I am unable to find a way to add a layer when an area is visible on the map any help or sample code will be useful for me.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current area of map displayed on screen and show your layer accordingly.

Step 1 : Get the total area of map covered on current screen. You can get the region by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056366/android-google-maps-how-to-get-the-area-which-is-currently-shown-in-screen-devi) link.

Step 2 : Get all the marker latitude and longitude from kml and check whether that exists between region bounds of step 1.

Step 3 : If there exists the latitude and longitude then simply draw a marker on the map.